# "Open to opportunities" vs. "open for opportunities"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

I want to know which sentence is correct and why:

> - I'm open to new opportunities.
> - I'm open for new opportunities.

Comment: Usually we are open *to* new opportunities, the public, and new ideas, but open *for* business, registrations, etc.

Comment: @medica do you know any general rules or exceptions what article to choose and when?

Comment: I wish there were easy rules, but there are so many prepositions, it's probably best to learn them case by case as you did here. You'll get a better feel for them with every use.

Comment: "Open *to*" often implies an event (encountering an opportunity, being shown to the public) where "open *for*" implies a (regular) state. However, this rule is more of a "feeling" rule than anything else, since "registrations" can be seen as events and "to the public" as a state.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is correct. "Open to something"  means that you're willing to consider something; that you're agreeable to hear or learn about new ideas and suggestions. For example: "He's open to any reasonable suggestions." So, in your case, "I'm open to new opportunities", means that you're willing to consider any new opportunities. As for "open for", I agree with [anongoodnurse](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159870/open-to-opportunities-vs-open-for-opportunities#comment333432_159870).